# How to draw an exact polygon with exact messurements

Tags: polygon-creation

I want to draw a polygons on a Google satellite map. I made a Shapefile to work in, but I can't find the right tool to make a polygon that is exact 20 x 20 or 40 x 10 or some other measure. As I start drawing now its just a messy polygon...

Can somebody give me some advice?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Whar units are you using 20m or 20km or 20ft or something else?

Comment: Sorry, QGIS. im using 20m units.